# can't install magento2 extension from backend. Why?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.2.2

I have installed magento 2.2.2 successfully. Now I trying Installed some extension from magento admin panel using web setup wizard option. I Find my extension and proceed to install. But it's stop on third step. Display don't any error.[image]

here is third step. 
[image]

Now, magento stay here. Please let me know what I need to do now?
I am new In magento 2. Please help. Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It happen some time that screen don't go away, but extension is installed. however if you check your frontend / admin in new tab you will see your extension is installed.

Comment: I have checked in vendor folder. Add admin also. No new extension is added. One month ego, I have downloaded an extension successfully using same process. But this time it's not working fine.

Comment: did you check in composer if there is any entry updated ?

Comment: Oh! I don't check it. Can you please help me. where i need to check?